# Mobile Compatilble vs. Mobile Separate Mobile Version

Tags: wordpress, jquery-mobile, mobile-website

I am building a website both mobile and pc version.But I am in a fix what should be used to do it.I have some question for which I am confused :
 1. make a website with separate mobile version and pc version and render page depending on the  device users use ?
 2. Another is a single version website that would be all device compatible.this can adapt the layout according to the device resolution ?
 3. if I do the thing I mentioned at point 1 , Can I built a site with wordpress and mobile version with jquery mobile ?
 4. If I use a mobile compatible wordpress template I mentioned in point 2, can I use all other plugin form outside?

Please Help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So what should I do? building two different version ?? if yes, Can I
>   use the wordpress for both? do you know any plugin or way to make both
>   pc and mobile version in wordpress ?

This is what I did to achieve what you are aiming for:

- Install WordPress as normal.
- Add the [Mobile Smart plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mobile-smart/) - or possibly mobile smart pro.
- Create a theme for regular desktop browsers and activate it in WordPress
- Create a completely separate theme for mobile browsers. You may wish to use the sample code supplied with the plugin; I created my own from scratch.
- Change the settings of Mobile Smart so that it knows which is your mobile theme
- Add content and enjoy!

Please read the documentation with Mobile Smart. It is important to understand what it is doing.

Also, remember that your two themes are completely separate, in completely separate directories, so you can use completely different functions.php, headers, footers, scripts, etc. as necessary.

Comment: you said --Create a completely separate theme for mobile browsers. You may wish to use the sample code supplied with the plugin; I created my own from scratch.

question : Can I use jquery mobile framework for that ?? or is it sufficient to to use the sample code supplied with the plugin? @Philip

Comment: Yes, you can use jquery mobile for that. I haven't tried the sample code with the plugin but it may work for you.

Comment: Don't mind, I have no credit/debit card.And thats why I couldn't purchase the mobile smart pro.If you have the plugin available to you now,would you please email the mobile smart pro plugin ?? I will be grateful to you. my email address is : ikaidul@yahoo.com

Comment: As this is commercial software I do not think it would be right for me to provide you with an unlicensed copy. Your best bet would be to contact the developer directly. You can find his contact details in the plugin page on wordpress.org

Answer (score 1):

Quote from https://github.com/ChristianPeters/crispy-mobile that I agree with:

> CSS media queries are nice. But not for mobile.
>
> They just add up code you send to your clients instead of reducing it for mobile devices.
>
> Imagine you want to make a responsive product page.
>
> ```
> Do you really want to deliver a big 90KB product photo, if a 15KB photo would already fill the mobile screen?
> Do you really want to compute personalized product recommendations if they are just hidden afterwards?
> Do you really want mobile devices to download and interpret your whole stylesheet if half of the interface elements are going to be hidden anyway?
> ```
>
> You don't.
>
> If you start mobile-first, don't let your mobile performance be affected by additional desktop features.
>
> Be kind, serve the clients exactly what they need.

If the mobile internet was fast enough and limits weren't as low as they are, I would probably think the other way. But we have to wait few years for that. For now in my opinion it is better to build seperate mobile website. But it is also very useful to have responsive design - that can't hurt even with separate mobile design.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to avoid too much subjectivity here, as everyone will have a different opinion.

1. Yes, I have this approach working well on my company website (www.achaleon.com). I was involved in the beta testing for a WordPress plugin called Mobile Smart Pro. It implements elements from a bigger open source project to detect mobile devices and apply a completely different theme to the mobile site. It has the advantage that you can create two completely separate themes and optimise every aspect of them for the device and the context in which it is being used. You can even serve up different content if you wish in the two versions.
2. This approach requires careful planning and thorough testing. It is also more demanding for the designer. I have friends in the WP community who have built sites this way. My understanding is that this requires stronger programming skills (you need to plan far more carefully than with a standard 'static' css implementation). They used cssgrid.net as a start point

Comment: So what should I do? building two different version ?? if yes, Can I use the wordpress for both? do you know any plugin or way to make both pc and mobile version in wordpress ? @Philip Jones